# chrome disable web security, why should that be allowed?

Tags: security, google-chrome, cors

as far as i know 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is used as part of CORS to limit which all hosts can request data from a given api server. This flag/variable value is set by the server as part of a response.

I did happen to stumble upon this [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) which says:

> Allow to you request any site with ajax from any source. Add to
>   response - 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header
>
> Developer tool.
>
> *Summary* Add to response header rule - 'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
>
> *Hint* Same behavior you can get just using chrome flags [http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags]
>
> chrome --disable-web-security
>
> or
>
> --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access --allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt

so that means from the client side I can change the response header. So it means that if i set on server :  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin : http://api.example.com' this setting can be overwritten by client 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *'. or may be I do not want to support cors - so i dont set it, but this will still show as if I do support CORS.

If that is the case, what is the point in having my server side setting?? isn't that left redundant??

May be I am being too naive here, and not getting the basics of it.

Answer (score 1):

CORS is a security feature to protect clients from CORF, or Cross Origin Request Forgery. It is not intended to secure servers, as a client can simply choose to ignore them.

An example of CORF would be visiting a website, and client-side code on that website interacts with another website on your behalf, do things like submitting data to a website, or reading data that requires authentication as you, all with your active authentication sessions.

Theoretically, without CORS, it would be possible to create a website that will fetch your email from a webmail provider (provided you are logged in at the time), and post it back to a server for malicious individuals to read.

To avoid this, you shouldn't browse the web with such security features disabled. It's available to ease development, not for general browsing.